# Flask and SQLAlchemy cause idle transactions on Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, flask, transactions, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that uses SQLAlchemy to access a PostgreSQL database. I'm following this [tutorial](https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-sqlalchemy-database-models/) to initiate my app in my init.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(engine_options={"pool_pre_ping":True})


def create_app():
    """Construct the core application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes  # Import routes
        db.create_all()  # Create sql tables for our data models

        return app
```

I've noticed that the db.create_all() call creates some idle transactions in my Postgres DB. The postgres query

```
SELECT backend_start, query_start, state_change, wait_event_type, wait_event, state, query, backend_type 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
order by state_change desc;
```

gives 4 rows of idle transactions with query field equal to ROLLBACK (image joined)[image]

If I comment the db.create_all() command, no idle transactions. Can someone explain the reason of such transactions and how to avoid them.

Comment: Idle connections are not a problem. They are probably kept open by a connection pool. `idle in transaction` would be a problem though.

Comment: Understood. Do you know why I see sometimes ROLLBACK, sometimes COMMIT in the query field of postgres query output?

Comment: It's the _last_ statement that was run in that session. If you see rollback or commit it simply means the transaction was ended properly - thus switching from "idle in transaction" to "idle"

Comment: If you want you can add an answer and I will mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: "Idle connections are not a problem". Well, it could be a problem for me since it consumes a slot in my db each time I do a session.commit(). If the limit is low (and this limit is not set by me but by the DBA), I can easily go over with my multiple pods where each is running the flask app.

Comment: For example, in my init file, I'm doing 2 separate session.execute() commands (each followed by a commit()) and it creates two idle transactions in Postgres. I've tried to close the session after commit but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy engine typically generates a connection pool. The engine will create connections up to maximum number of connections in the pool with each new query. For example, if the size of the connection pool is 5 then the first five queries will create a new connection pool but then these connections will be reused for future queries.

You can control the size of the connection pool via the `SQL_ENGINE_OPTIONS` object in [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/) and the specific options are inherited from the connection options in [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html)